# How do I resolve a $q.when promise in unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, promise

I'm using `$q.when` to convert third-party promises (those returned by PouchDB)
into Angular promises.

Given:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test', [])
  .service('pouchdb', function($q, $window) {
    var db = new $window.PouchDB('test');
    this.info = function() {
      return $q.when(db.info.apply(db, arguments));
    };
  })
  .controller('test', function($scope, pouchdb) {
    pouchdb.info()
      .then(function(info) {
        $scope.result = info;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        $scope.result = error;
      });
  });
```

… in the browser, `info` is returned and `$scope` updated correctly. However,
given the following unit test (Jasmine 2.x):

```
describe('Q when tests', function() {
  beforeEach(module('test'));

  var $rootScope, pouchdb;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, pouchdb) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    pouchdb = pouchdb;
  }));

  it('should resolve a promise', function(done) {
    pouchdb.info()
      .then(function(info) {
        expect(info).toBeDefined();
      })
      .finally(done);
    $rootScope.$apply();
  });
});
```

… `info` is never resolved and Jasmine (via Karma & PhantomJS) throws:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

By calling `$rootScope.$apply()`, I'd expect a digest to be triggered and the
promise to be resolved. How do I resolve the promise in this case?

Note, I've loaded `es5-shim` for `bind`/`apply` support in PhantomJS.

Edit: I've tried moving `$rootScope.$apply()` to the top of the test (and in an `afterEach` block), alternating to `$rootScope.$digest()` and increasing Jasmine's timeout (`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;`).

Comment: maybe you can try $rootScope.$digest(); instead of $apply() or calling pouchdb.info().resolve(); or both. Another possibility is that the http request take too long and you can set a higher timeout. You can also look at mock in jasmine (spyOn), except if you also want to test the webservice.

Comment: move $rootScope.$apply(); to the top of your test. The digest loop will resolve all unresolved promises. After you've run it, you will have access to the resolved value.

Comment: @BorisCharpentier, @bengro, I've tried your suggestions to no avail (see edit). `pouchdb.info()` does not contain a `.resolve` property (it's a `$q` promise). Spying on `pouchdb.info` shows `info()` is called correctly, but not on `pouchdb.info().then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwittingly, I resolved the issue by manually injecting `ng`:

```
describe('Working Q when tests', function() {
  var pouchdb;
  beforeEach(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'test']);
    var pouchDB = $injector.get('pouchdb');
    pouchdb = pouchDB('db');
  });

  it('should resolve a promise', function(done) {
    pouchdb.info()
      .then(function(info) {
        expect(info).toBeDefined();
      })
      .finally(done);
  });
});
```